# How to assign subsequent columns in csv to array using strtok in C

Tags: c, csv, strtok

I am trying to write a simple program that will allow the user to extract data from a csv file after specifying what rows and columns they would like to extract. The program accepts inputs for the start row (can be any number, not necessarily 1) and the final row desired. The same principle applies for the columns. The output is then assigned to a multidimensional array that will later be passed to functions for calculations.

I am having issues with using strtok to extract a column that is not the first as from my understanding, strtok has to read a file sequentially?

i have been using this project to teach myself C, so have had many iterations of this principle to develop my knowledge. I have successfully read csv files, so i understand the basic principles of strtok in csv files.

If i was using the first column to read from, then i can just use strtok as i have been;

```
var[i][0] = atof(strtok(buf, ","));
var[i][j] = atof(strtok(NULL, ","));
```

however to read from column 2 onwards, the above code still has to be used as strtok is sequential, but not assign column 0 to the variable. The only rough method i have working is to introduce a temporary variable, place all columns into that, and extract the columns specified by the use, but this is undesirable.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdint.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void CSV_Col_read(int r, int c, int start_row, int start_col, float var[r][c])
{

char buf[1024];
float temp[r][c];

  FILE *fp = fopen("PV_Data.csv", "r");

  if(!fp)
  {
    printf("Could Not Open File\n");
  }
  int i = 0;
  int index_row = 0;

  while(fgets(buf, sizeof buf, fp))
  {  
      index_row++;
      if (index_row >= start_row){
      if(i >= r - start_row + 1){
          break;
      }

      if (c == 1){
      var[i][0] = atof(strtok(buf, ","));
  }
      else if(start_col >= 2){
          temp[i][0] = atof(strtok(buf, ","));

      for (int j = 1; j <= c-1; j++)
      {       
      temp[i][j] = atof(strtok(NULL, ","));
      }

      for (int I = -1; I <= 2; I++){

      var[i][I+1] = temp[i][start_col + I];
      }
      }
      else{

              var[i][0] = atof(strtok(buf, ","));

      for (int j = 1; j <= c-1; j++)
      {       
      var[i][j] = atof(strtok(NULL, ","));
      }
  }
  i++;
}
  }
        fclose(fp);
}

void printData(int r, int c, int start_row, int start_col, float var[r][c])
{
if ( c == 1){
for (int i = 1; i <= (r - start_row); i++)
    {
    printf("%f\n", var[i][0]);
    }
}
else{
    for(int i = 0; i <= (r - start_row); i++)
    {
        printf("%f", var[i][0]);


        for(int j = 1; j <= (c - start_col); j++)
        {
            printf("\t");
            printf("%f", var[i][j]);   
    }
    printf("\n");
    }
}
}
int main()
{
    int start_row = 705;
    int start_col = 3;
    int r = 720;
    int c = 5;
    float var[r][c];

    (void) CSV_Col_read(r, c, start_row, start_col, var);

    printData(r, c, start_row, start_col, var);
}
```

the code above is not "insert correct programming word for idiot proof" however as i know i have only specfied the elseif() statement for one scenario. Is this method of a temporary variable the way to go or is there a much cleaner way to approach this? I am not asking for code to fix this and am perfectly happy with an answer that directs me to a learning resource.

Thanks

Comment: One usually loops until [`strtok`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok) returns a `NULL` pointer. But be aware of the shortcomings of [`strtok`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok), like how it can't handle consecutive separators the way you want in a CSV file. There are also many other problems and non-trivial special- and corner-cases that makes CSV files much harder to parse than it seems. Therefore I always recommend that you find a library that will do it for you.

Comment: I'll look into the loop aspect. I have seen that strtok can be awkward with data that is not just simple numbers in columns. If i was doing this for a purpose other than teaching myself C, then i think your right, why do development someone else has spent weeks on, However, anything i find that is a problem to solve can only help me learn!

Answer (score 0):

For something simple where I know the input file will be well-formed and without "empty" values, then I might be doing something like this:

```
float values[rows][columns] = { 0 };  // Initialize all to zero

char line[512];  // Hopefully large enough

unsigned r;  // Row index

// Loop to get all rows, taking care to not go out of bounds
for (r = 0; r < rows && fgets(line, sizeof line, fp) != NULL; ++r)
{
    unsigned c = 0;  // Column index

    // Get the first column value
    char *current = strtok(line, ",");

    // Loop to get all columns
    while (c < columns && current != NULL)
    {
        values[r][c] = atof(current);

        ++c;  // Increase to next column
        current = strtok(NULL, ",");  // Get next (if any) column value
    }
}

// Here the whole file will have been read and parsed, and the values
// from the file will be in the array `values`.
```

Comment: Forgive me if i have missed something, as my C knowledge is lacking, but i can't see where the values for what rows and columns are desired is entered or impemented. I am going to be implementing this principle on files that can have 1000-100,000 rows and over 360 columns. because of this i was looking into how i could choose for example ONLY the 5th and sixth column to reduce read time, perform my calculations and clear those values before moving onto the next section of calculations. is this possible? thanks for answering though

Comment: @RossHanna You still have to read the whole lines, which of course means reading the whole file. Of course you can read a small part of a line, see if the wanted column is in that line, and if not read a little more, but this very quickly become very complicated and not at all trivial. The thing is, there's no guarantee that all elements in a record (row) are of the same size, have the same number of characters. Which of course also means that no two lines will be of the same size. You can't just find the position in the first line and assume it's the same for every line.